# multiple rows or one column [sql performance]

Tags: sql, performance, reddit

I'm struggling with this simple idea.
Look at reddit, when you sign up for a new account.. you automatically subscribe to some default channels.

I want to do the same with my website.

I know I could do the simple and stupid **user_chan** with id, user_id, chan_id

if **chan** is like this :

```
ID | NAME
1  | videos
2  | pictures
```

**user_chan** would be like this (i'm user 1)

```
ID | USER_ID | CHAN_ID
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
```

I'm trying to be very clear here :D

I guess that's how reddit works. But every time a user signs up, they must have to insert a dozen of rows. And I guess they have tons of users !!

So is a solution inside **user** table like this more clever ?:

```
ID | USER_NICKNAME | CHANS
1  | me            | 1,2
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use one column to store multiple values. This is a denormalization that will cause pain later. E.g., when you need to query which user has channel 3, you are going to have to use `LIKE`, which will perform badly. When you need to remove just one channel of the several the user has, it gets even harder.

With most databases, you can insert multiple rows with one `INSERT` statement. The exact syntax varies by platform; in SQL Server, you can do this:

```
insert into user_chan
(USER_ID, CHANID)
select 7634, 3
union all
select 7634, 27
union all
select 7634, 9
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think about "when you need to query which user has channel 3". Right. That's the situation which tells me to chose solution 1

Comment: +1, If you _ever_ find yourself using parts of columns, you're doing something wrong. Per-row functions do not scale well. You will be querying this DB _far_ more often than writing to it. Plan accordingly. And I'd even question the need for a single insert statement. Transactions will do the same thing and it won't be done often enough to cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Or, use an XML column to store the multiple values as you suggested.  This can have an XML index and can be queried / updated etc as you would a relational table (albeit more complex syntax).